# Can anyone help me with why .substring() isn't working with setInterval roll out text?

Tags: javascript, html, substring, setinterval

the idea is to target a pre-defined invisible P element with text inside in the document and to make it roll out and visible again(the function that makes the text-invisible upon body load event isn't included).

I've commented the line of code that doesn't work with the substring method on it.

```
var tally = 0; //global. 




var rollTextOut = function(x){ //make re-usable for all roll-outs. 
var anim = setInterval(function(){sequence()}, 50);

function sequence(){

  tally++; 

 if(x===1){



     var pHidden1 = document.getElementById("roll1");
     pHidden1.style.background="#fff";
     pHidden1.style.zIndex="2";
     pHidden1.style.visibility="visible";

    var text = pHidden1.innerHTML; //targets the p text inside html doc.

    pHidden1.innerHTML = text.substring(0, tally); //<why doesn't this work?




 }
 else if(x===2){
     var pHidden2 = document.getElementById("roll2");
     pHidden2.style.background="#fff";
     pHidden2.style.zIndex="2";
     pHidden2.style.visibility="visible";
      pHidden2.innerHTML = tally;
 }

  else if(x===3){
     var pHidden3 = document.getElementById("roll3");
     pHidden3.style.background="#fff";
     pHidden3.style.zIndex="2";
     pHidden3.style.visibility="visible";
     pHidden3.innerHTML = tally;
 }

  else{
     var pHidden4 = document.getElementById("roll4");
     pHidden4.style.background="#fff";
     pHidden4.style.zIndex="2";
     pHidden4.style.visibility="visible";
     pHidden4.innerHTML = tally;
 }




     if(tally===15){
       clearInterval(anim); 
       tally=0; 

      }




};

};
```

Any help and suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: How can you expect `substring(0, tally)` to take any text if tally ==0 ??

Comment: Because you replace the text so next time around it is not there!

Comment: Tally's in global scope chsdk so it keeps incrementing right? epascarello, can you elloberate I think I catch your drift.

Comment: Your code isn't easy to read and you should really put that in a for loop and use an array instead of multiple pHidden variables.

It seems `tally` is 1 when you call substring, so I can't tell what the problem is there. However, the second time you loop around, it won't work because when you get the innerHTML, it will only be the one char you put back in.

Comment: You replace the text on the first iteration so the innerHTML is only one letter, Next iteration, you try to increment it, but you removed the default text so you can not add more characters because they are not there.

Comment: ok, jacque shall try and clean it up abit, and epascarello, i see what you mean i think. ty both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You remove the default text so you can not increment the next letter since it no longer exists. So store a reference to it.

```
var pHidden1 = document.getElementById("roll1");
if (!pHidden1.myDefaultText) { 
    pHidden1.myDefaultText = pHidden.textContent || pHidden.innerText;
}
var text = pHidden1.myDefaultText; 
pHidden1.innerHTML = text.substring(0, tally);
```

Comment: Ok , cheers! I think i gotcha'. massive help. gunna go back and tweak code.